# ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, jscript

I am trying to update a Google map from an sql server.

there are arrays define in C# as shown below

```
foreach (Location item in lst) {
  ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(UpdatePanel1, "infoarray", "'"+item.Description.ToString()+"'");
  ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(UpdatePanel1, "lonarray", item.Longitude.ToString());
  ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(UpdatePanel1, "latarray", item.Latitude.ToString());
  ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(UpdatePanel1, "bounce", item.Bounce.ToString()); 
}
```

now when these arrays are called by jscript

```
//loop to set the markers
for (var i = 0; i < lonarray.length; i++) {
  //get the longtitude from the longtitude array this array is set from the C# code 
  longt = lonarray[i];
  //get the latitude from the latitude array this array is set from the C# code
  lat = latarray[i];
  //set a title
  var title = 'test';
```

there is a runtime error saying that lonarray is undefined.

what am I doing wrong??